# Inserting node at the end of linkedlist in C++

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

Below is code for inserting a node at the end of a linked list. I am getting a segmentation fault. Please help!!

```
Node* Insert(Node *head,int data)
{
    struct Node *last=head;

    struct Node* n=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));


    n->data=data;
    n->next=NULL;

    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=n;
    }

    while(last->next!=NULL)
    {
        last=last->next;
    }

    last->next=n;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is returning the numeric literal 0, but its return type is "Node *", so as soon as you try to use the return value of the function, you're headed for trouble.
What did you intend to return? The head of the modified list? Or the newly-appended Node? Either way, it's not returning them.

Comment: i would like to return the head of modifiedd linked list

Comment: You're already passing the head of the linked list to the function, though, so you won't gain anything useful by making it the function's return value.
But if you want to return it, then it's as simple as: `return head;`
If head was NULL when the function was called, then you'll be returning the new node, otherwise you'll be returning the function's 1st argument.